# Can't get all JSON to show up

Tags: javascript

It will always display the "cretetion" associated link JSON as the others are overwritten. So I tried incrementing to get all of them, but it didn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion"];

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length ; i++) {
      var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + users[i];
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('online-id').innerHTML += (xmlhttp.responseText + "<br />");
      }else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
        console.log('There was an error 400');
      }else {
        console.log('Something else other than 200 was returned.');
      }
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
   }
}

var onlineButton = document.getElementById('online-button-id');
onlineButton.addEventListener('click', loadXMLDoc, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your code here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/VbkKc9QuVALAYLpujSdo?p=preview

First, the callback `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is overwritten every iteration of the loop so only the last element will be handled.
you should create and manage the XMLHttp object inside the loop, one for each element of your user array.

Secondy and most important you must wrap `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` inside an Immediate invoked function otherwise each callback will use the last xmlhttp object then you will be getting the last result all the time, as you were saying above.

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length ; i++) { 
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + users[i];

  (function(xmlhttp){
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById('online-id').innerHTML += (xmlhttp.responseText + "<br/><br/>");
        }else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          console.log('There was an error 400');
        }else {  
          console.log('Something else other than 200 was returned.');
        }
      }
    }
 })(xmlhttp)

 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new XMLHttpRequest for each iteration of the loop instead of re-using the same one. i.e.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length ; i++) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
```